# Save to Camera Roll - this movie format is not supported

Tags: ios, ios6

I am getting the following error message when 'Save to Camera Roll' is clicked from the UIDocumentInteractionController

> 2013-02-07 00:50:56.250 Application[4101:907] Video /private/var/mobile/Applications/DD3719D0-E32D-4FED-B7B2-583015145649/tmp/Photo_130206_1913.jpeg cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12847 "This movie format is not supported." UserInfo=0x1d59fea0 {NSLocalizedDescription=This movie format is not supported.}

First thing I notice is how the log suggests the jpeg is a Video. To verify this isn't the case I sent myself the image through email and ran a couple commands:

```
> file -I image.jpeg
image/jpeg; charset=binary

> identify image.jpeg (ImageMagick)
JPEG 3264x2448 3264x2448+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 5.008MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Both show the image is a jpeg. Has anyone seen this before? Any suggestions on a workaround?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this same message in my console. However, when I went to check my camera roll I found that the image I was attempting to save was actually saved successfully, despite the "error" message. So this may not be a real problem.